# Return a value from a form POST using Razor and AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, razor

I have a simple, one-field html form of which I'm posting the value to a server side script (written in Razor) using AJAX. The form user has to guess a particular value and will receive a message depending if it's correct or not.

Is it possible to return a message using the method described below? Ideally I would like to return the variable "message" from my server-side script and display the value to the user on the front end.

My HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="value" name="value" />
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

My Ajax call:

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var dataString = "value=" + $("#value").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/post",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.returnedValue);
        }
    });         
});
```

My server-side script:

```
if(IsPost)
{
    string value = Request.Form["value"];
    string message = "";

    if(value.ToString() == "CorrectAnswer"){
        message = "Correct!";
        return message;
    }else{
        message = "Wrong!";
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be possible, I'd say you need to replace `data.returnedValue` by `data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server page is an Asp.net page (.aspx), you probably need to use `Response.Write`

```
    string value = Request.Form["value"];
    string message = "";

    if(value.ToString() == "CorrectAnswer"){
        message = "Correct!";
        return message;
    }else{
        message = "Wrong!";

    }
   Response.Write(message );
```

Also, This is not going to be a postback event. So you do not need to check that.

and in your script,

```
success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
```

Comment: This could work but I would much prefer not to evaluate magic strings. Also, you should add error: function(data) {} to your .ajax() call just in case anything goes wrong. Lastly, why not use a GET? You are requesting a message and data can be sent within a GET. The response size will almost always be smaller anyway. 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/